# Are there any ways to do subqueries in a Cypher query in AGE?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have created a few nodes called routes and have given several relationships that are travel times, using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('Map', $$
    CREATE (a:Route {name: 'A'}), 
        (b:Route {name: 'B'}),
        (c:Route {name: 'C'}),
        (d:Route {name: 'D'}),
        (e:Route {name: 'E'}),
        (f:Route {name: 'F'}),
        (a)-[:Connects {time: 4}]->(b),
        (a)-[:Connects {time: 2}]->(c),
        (b)-[:Connects {time: 6}]->(c),
        (b)-[:Connects {time: 9}]->(d),
        (c)-[:Connects {time: 1}]->(d),
        (c)-[:Connects {time: 8}]->(e),
        (c)-[:Connects {time: 3}]->(f),
        (d)-[:Connects {time: 3}]->(a),
        (e)-[:Connects {time: 10}]->(b),
        (f)-[:Connects {time: 2}]->(e)
$$) AS (x agtype);
```

I have then attempted to find all possible connections for specified routes along with the total time travelled, for example from Route 'A' to Route 'F' using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('Map', $$
    MATCH paths = (a:Route {name: 'A'})-[:Connects *]->(b:Route {name: 'F'})
    WITH paths, relationships(paths) AS rels
    UNWIND rels AS rel
    WITH nodes(paths) AS nodes,
        collect(rel.time) AS routes,
        sum(rel.time) AS travelTime
    RETURN nodes, routes, travelTime
$$) AS (nodes agtype, routes agtype, travelTime agtype)
ORDER BY travelTime;
```

Which gave me the result:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      nodes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |          routes           | traveltime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | [2, 3]                    | 5
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | [4, 6, 3]                 | 13
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]                                                                                                                                                                 | [4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 3]        | 19
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]                                                                                                                                                                 | [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 3]        | 19
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | [4, 9, 3, 2, 3]           | 21
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131973, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "E"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | [2, 8, 10, 6, 3]          | 29
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131973, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "E"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex] | [4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 3, 2, 3] | 45
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131973, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "E"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex] | [2, 8, 10, 9, 3, 4, 6, 3] | 45
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131973, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "E"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex] | [4, 9, 3, 2, 8, 10, 6, 3] | 45
(9 rows)

(END)
```

I would like to make a subquery in the Cypher query in order to print only the names of each node in the `nodes` column but am unsure how to do so. For example, I would like the first row first column of the outputted table to be `{"A", "C", "F"}` instead. I have found out about the `CALL {}` clause from the [Neo4j documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/) which seems to be what I am looking for in this case; however, the clause doesn't seem to be recognized when I ran it in AGE.

Comment: What version of apacheAGE and postgreSQL are you using? Because im gettint an error 
```ERROR:  UNWIND clause does not support agtype edge```

Comment: This issue has been resolved for PG/AGE 11, which I am running on.

Comment: By 'resolved' you mean you found the answer yourself?

Comment: The `UNWIND` error I mean. It works on PG/AGE 11.

Comment: My understanding is that CALL {} is not working as intended. Simple queries are failing to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer may be coming a bit late, but I hope it helps. AGE may not recognise the `CALL` clause yet, but here's a solution you could use.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('Map', $$
    MATCH paths = (a:Route {name: 'A'})-[:Connects *]->(b:Route {name: 'F'})
    WITH paths, relationships(paths) AS rels

    UNWIND rels AS rel
    WITH nodes(paths) AS nodes,
        collect(rel.time) AS routes,
        sum(rel.time) AS travelTime

    UNWIND nodes AS node
    RETURN collect(properties(node).name), routes, travelTime
$$) AS (nodes agtype, routes agtype, travelTime agtype)
ORDER BY travelTime;
```

The result of the query should return the following output.

```
                     nodes                     |          routes           | traveltime 
-----------------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------
 ["F", "C", "A"]                               | [2, 3]                    | 5
 ["A", "C", "B", "F"]                          | [4, 6, 3]                 | 13
 ["A", "F", "C", "B", "A", "D", "C"]           | [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 3]        | 19
 ["A", "F", "C", "A", "D", "C", "B"]           | [4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 3]        | 19
 ["A", "C", "A", "D", "B", "F"]                | [4, 9, 3, 2, 3]           | 21
 ["F", "C", "B", "E", "C", "A"]                | [2, 8, 10, 6, 3]          | 29
 ["A", "D", "A", "C", "E", "B", "C", "F", "B"] | [4, 9, 3, 2, 8, 10, 6, 3] | 45
 ["F", "C", "E", "B", "D", "A", "C", "A", "B"] | [4, 6, 8, 10, 9, 3, 2, 3] | 45
 ["D", "A", "C", "E", "B", "A", "B", "C", "F"] | [2, 8, 10, 9, 3, 4, 6, 3] | 45
(9 rows)
```